# Java - How to use JProgressBar with SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, jprogressbar

I am creating a Java application with a downloader. My problem is, the progress bar is not working. I want my progress bar to show the download progress but failed. Here is some part of my code. The progressbar just stuck at 0%...

Download.class

```
public void startDownload()
{
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    FutureTask<Void> verDownloader = new FutureTask<Void>(vd);
    FutureTask<Void> launcher = new FutureTask<Void>(dd);
    executor.execute(verDownloader);
    executor.execute(launcher);
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

VersionDownloader.class

```
public class VersionDownloader implements Callable<Void>, PropertyChangeListener
{
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception
    {
                    done = false;
                    final SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                URL fileURL = new URL(url);
                                org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyURLToFile(fileURL, path);
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {

                            }
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void done()
                        {
                            done = true;

                            try
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            }
                            catch (InterruptedException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    };
                    worker.execute();
                    worker.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
                    worker.get();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
    {
        if(!done)
        {
            int progress_a = progress;
            //launcher.frame.progress is a JProgressBar
            launcher.frame.progress.setValue(progress_a);
        }
    }


}
```

Is that any code wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This sort of thing is less trivial than it sounds.  `copyURLToFile()` is going to block until the copy is completed, so that will only give you two events - 0% and 100%.

If you want to show progress while you do the download, there is one prerequisite:  You must know the file **length** before the download starts (so you can compute percentages).  You could get that - maybe - by issuing an HTTP `HEAD` request before starting the copy - but whether the `Content-Length` field is there in the response depends on the server - for chunked encoding, you don't get this information (though you might be able to force some servers to tell you by issuing an HTTP 1.0 request).  Failing that, you could cheat and pick an arbitrary number of bytes.

Once you have the length or an approximation, you can either

- Run a timer and periodically check the number of bytes downloaded so far, and compare that with the size, OR
- Open the URL as an `InputStream` and do your own loop to copy the bytes, and on each loop iteration, update the progress bar

Either way, make sure you use `EventQueue.invokeLater()` to update the progress bar's `value` property or you may have deadlock issues - it is not safe to modify Swing components from any thread but the event thread.

Comment: File length = file size? My downloader will parse a XML file and get the content of `URL` in the XML file and download it using Common-IO.

Comment: Yes, file length = file size.  HTTP protocol allows for two ways to send a file - old-fashioned HTTP 1.0 download, where the ``Content-Length`` header tells you how many bytes you will download before you download them.  HTTP 1.1 offers "chunked" encoding, where the server keeps passing small chunks of bytes, each one preceded by the number of bytes in that chunk.  In that case you don't know how long a file you are downloading.  So for chunked encoding, you don't know how many bytes you're going to get.

If you know the average size, you can guess at it...

Comment: But no matter what, if you want to show actual progress - what percentage done you are - you need some way to listen to the download while it is in progress and update it.  You can always do "indeterminate" mode on your progress bar, in which case accurately knowing how many bytes are left to download is not needed.

Comment: It is hard to use InputStream for my file cuz i have to do a lot of mkdir and something. That's why i use Common-IO. Can you give me some example code plz? My XML file also have `<Size>` for each file

Answer (score 1):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for a working example that uses a SwingWorker.

Start with something that works and make changes for your particular requirement. If you still have problems then post a `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.